# Html img tag in v-tooltip not working for vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I'm using the package v-tooltip for Vue.js, I'm basically trying to put html img tag inside but the img is not rendering :

[image]

And here is my code :

```html
<router-link to="/" class="routerlinks" v-tooltip="{content: `<img src='@/assets/keys/shift.png' />`, html: true}">
   <li class="link">{{$t('home')}}</li>
</router-link>
```

here is my project structure :

src/
--assets/
----keys/
------shif.png
--components/
----layout/
-----Navbar.vue

here is the tooltip content :

[image]

Does someone have any idea ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: check if you are getting correct image address

Comment: In fact I am getting the correct img address... :/

Comment: can you try `<img src='~@/assets/keys/shift.png' />` and using .. to navigate to the src directory `<img src='../../assets/keys/shift.png' />`

Comment: Both aren't working

Comment: what's your directory structure? how many ../ did you add?

Comment: Can you `inspect element` and check if the image tag are not embedded as string

Comment: Check my edit for project structure

Comment: given your project structure, you should do `<img src='../../../assets/keys/shift.png' />`

Comment: Check my last edit, still not working..

Comment: quel dommage...

Comment: Are images elsewhere in the project working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If images are working elsewhere in the project, then it's a v-tooltip issue. It seems to display content other than text, you can use the v-popover component. try [it](https://akryum.github.io/v-tooltip/#/) instead. For reference, check out the [docs](https://github.com/Akryum/v-tooltip#popover-component-reference).